# Opening various links from a column in Firefox

Tags: excel, vba, firefox

I'm trying to make a macro for requesting reports to a reporting portal but without opening the portal. At the moment the code below works well for me, but I would like to get a little help.

At this moment I'm trying to add a Macro to download the links that are marked as "Yes" in a column.

For example, column H is going to be "Download?", while rows from 5 to 11 are different reports and would get a "Yes" or "No" in column H. What I want the macro to do is open the links in column L if they are marked as "Yes" in column H.

What I tried to do is add, for example, an "If(H5="Yes";l5;"")" this way I got a column with only the links marked as "Yes" the problem that I get when I run the macro is that it opens blank pages plus the reports I marked as "Yes".

```
Sub Test_OpenFireFoxNewTab()
 OpenInFireFoxNewTab (Range("l12").Value)
 OpenInFireFoxNewTab (Range("l11").Value)
 OpenInFireFoxNewTab (Range("l10").Value)
 OpenInFireFoxNewTab (Range("l9").Value)
 OpenInFireFoxNewTab (Range("l8").Value)
 OpenInFireFoxNewTab (Range("l7").Value)
End Sub



Sub OpenInFireFoxNewTab(url As String)
 Dim pathFireFox As String
 pathFireFox = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
 If Dir(pathFireFox) = "" Then pathFireFox = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
 If Dir(pathFireFox) = "" Then
   MsgBox "FireFox Path Not Found", vbCritical, "Macro Ending"
   Exit Sub
 End If
 Shell """" & pathFireFox & """" & " -new-tab " & url, vbHide
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!!

I'm new to VBA, tried to search for a solution for this but couldn't find nothing :(

Regards!

Comment: Remove these parentheis: `OpenInFireFoxNewTab (Range("l12").Value)` - That is a subroutine, not a function, so they cause problems.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but if I delete that parenthesis no link would open as that subroutines are what is asking Firefox to open the links in the mentioned cells. How it should be done if the way I wrote is incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: I guess i wasn't clear enough...  it's supposed to look like this: `OpenInFireFoxNewTab Range("l12").Value`

Comment: You do not enclose the argument(s) of the subroutine inside of parenthesis when you call it like you do when you are using a function.